# number values only display one at a time from click, why is it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I assume its the forEach method preventing multiple numbers to be selected. But not sure what else to use so that they all display.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="calculator" class="calc">
<input type="field" id="userinput" placeholder="0">

    <button  value= 7 class="numbers" id= "seven" >7</button>
    <button value =8 class="numbers" id= "eight">8</button>
    <button value =9 class="numbers"id= "nine">9</button>
    <button value =* class="operator"id= "multiply">*</button>
    <button value =4 class="numbers" id= "four">4</button>
    <button value =5 class="numbers" id=  "five">5</button>
    <button value =6 class="numbers" id= "six">6</button>
    <button value =- class="operator" id= "subtract">-</button>
    <button value =1 class="numbers" id= "one">1</button>
    <button value =2 class="numbers" id= "two">2</button>
    <button value =3 class="numbers" id=  "three">3</button> 
    <button value =+ class ="operator" id= "add">+</button>   
    <button value =/ class ="operator" id= "divide">/</button>
    
    <button class="clear" value ="" id= "clr">C</button>
    <button value = "" class="delete" id ="del">DEL</button>
    <button value ="=" class = "equals" id= "equal">=</button>
</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
let display = document.getElementById("userinput");
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.calc > .numbers');


numberButtons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.onclick = function (btn) {
      
        display.placeholder = btn.target.value;
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the placeholder every time a button is clicked. If you want to display multiple, you should be appending instead:

```js
let display = document.getElementById("userinput");
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.calc > .numbers');


numberButtons.forEach(btn => {
  btn.onclick = function(btn) {

    display.placeholder += btn.target.value;
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="calculator" class="calc">
    <input type="field" id="userinput" placeholder="0">

    <button value=7 class="numbers" id="seven">7</button>
    <button value=8 class="numbers" id="eight">8</button>
    <button value=9 class="numbers" id="nine">9</button>
    <button value=* class="operator" id="multiply">*</button>
    <button value=4 class="numbers" id="four">4</button>
    <button value=5 class="numbers" id="five">5</button>
    <button value=6 class="numbers" id="six">6</button>
    <button value=- class="operator" id="subtract">-</button>
    <button value=1 class="numbers" id="one">1</button>
    <button value=2 class="numbers" id="two">2</button>
    <button value=3 class="numbers" id="three">3</button>
    <button value=+ class="operator" id="add">+</button>
    <button value=/ class="operator" id="divide">/</button>

    <button class="clear" value="" id="clr">C</button>
    <button value="" class="delete" id="del">DEL</button>
    <button value="=" class="equals" id="equal">=</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realise "+=" was append!